# Do we need to take our marriage certificate to show to a hotel in New Delhi?

Tags: india, hotels, spouses

My wife and I are planning to go to India in a little over a week. We have a booking at The Metropolitan Hotel & Spa New Delhi. I have been reading about issues with New Delhi hotels giving rooms to unmarried couples. As we have just been married, my wife's passport is still in her maiden name (we are both UK citizens).

Should we take along our marriage certificate or will we encounter no issues?

Comment: Have you asked the hotel about this?

Comment: @pnuts I don't know about what OP read, but these are revealing: http://www.thenewsminute.com/lives/507 and more recently http://www.pocketlawyer.com/blog/get-room-unmarried-couples/

Comment: @that's precisely my thinking and I could find nothing on the Met's web site that has similar language.

Answer (score 5):

From my personal experiences travelling around Delhi with family and staying in hotels, I am certain you will not face any problems as long as you have a valid ID card and the credit card on which the booking was made.

I could only gather this article online:

[Booking.com's guideline while staying in Metropolitan Hotel](https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/nikko.html)

If you are still unsure, I think you should drop a quick email to the hotel staff at `info@hotelmetdelhi.com`. I am sure they will respond to you and clarify your concerns.

The marriage certificate issue is raised if the hotels have explicitly mentioned in their guidelines that one is mandatory, or the couples look suspicious.

I am sure you are going to be fine.

I hope you have loads of fun and a safe trip!!